# React-query optimistic update on mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

everyone! I'm new to react-query and I was trying to make an optimistic update, using mutation function, but faced a problem, that I can not fetch a previous value from the query. What am I doing wrong?

previousCurrentPost - always return a value, that already been updated

My onMutate func:

```
{
      onMutate: async (postOrComment: any, emojiType?: string) => {

      
        await queryClient.cancelQueries(['currentPost'])

        // Snapshot the previous value
        const previousCurrentPost = queryClient.getQueryData(['currentPost'])


        // Optimistically update to the new value
        queryClient.setQueryData(['currentPost'], (oldPost: any) => {
          const updated = { ...oldPost }
         
          updated.state.is_liked = !oldPost.state.is_liked
          updated.stat.like_count = postOrComment.state.is_liked
            ? oldPost.stat.like_count + 1
            : oldPost.stat.like_count - 1
          if (emojiType) {
            updated.state.like_emoji = emojiType
          }
          return updated
        })
        
        return { previousCurrentPost }
      }
```

Comment: Try this `const previousCurrentPost = {...queryClient.getQueryData(['currentPost'])}`

Comment: @VitaliyRayets thx for the help, but doesnt work :(

Comment: Try with deep clone `const previousCurrentPost = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(queryClient.getQueryData(['currentPost'])))`

Comment: @VitaliyRayets damn, you are right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because { ...oldPost } only do a shallow copy not a deep copy .

So oldPost.state and updated.state are the same object and when you do your assignment it's updating in oldPost and in updated

Comment: true, thanks for help

Comment: please use `immer` if you want to mutate data structures. In everything React, it is better to work immutably.